# How to compute the totient function when the input is not a prime?

Tags: totient-function

I've been searching on google how to solve this question but I only understand how to solve when it's a prime, which should be $\phi(p)=p-1$ for prime $p$ if I've understand correctly.

But the question is "Find the Euler totient function of $272$."

$272$ is not a prime, so how would I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Do you know the definition of the [totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)? It's defined for all natural numbers, not just for primes.

Comment: If you know the prime decomposition of $n$ then you can easily compute $\varphi(n)$. If you don't know the formula then it's strange you were given this exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that the totient function is multiplicative so for coprime $m,n$ $\phi(m\times n)=\phi(m)\times\phi(n)$ and that for primes $p$, $\phi(p^k)=p^{k-1}(p-1)$. Now decompose $272$ into prime powers.